# (Repost Because Original Post Didn't Have All The Code) Button Not Working Application Has Been Destroyed

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am receiving an error message that says that the application has been destroyed. I already  got a response on an earlier incomplete version of the code that didn't fix the issue so I am getting a little concerned. I am very new to tkinter so I'm not too good at this.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import glob

root = Tk()

e = Entry(root, width = 50)
e.pack()
root.title("Insert GUI Title Here")
root.geometry('600x400+50+50')
root.resizable(False, False)

nameDirections = []
directions = []



def openSmFile():
    folPath = filedialog.askdirectory()
    return folPath


root.mainloop()


def checkDirections():
    folPath = openSmFile()
    for fpath in glob.iglob(f'{folPath}/*'):
        if (fpath.endswith('.sm')):
            file = open(fpath,"r")
            lines = []
            lines = file.readlines()

            left = 0
            down = 0
            up = 0
            right = 0
            beats = 0

            for line in lines:  
                i = 0
                if not ("," in  line or "." in line or "#" in line or ";" in line or "-" in line or line == ""):
                    for alpha in line:
                        if i == 0 and alpha != "0":
                            left += 1
                        if i == 1 and alpha != "0":
                            down += 1
                        if i == 2 and alpha != "0":
                            up += 1
                        if i == 3 and alpha != "0":
                            right += 1
                        i += 1
                        beats += 1
                
            print ("There are " + str(left) + " lefts in this song.")
            print ("There are " + str(down) + " downs in this song.")
            print ("There are " + str(up) + " ups in this song.")
            print ("There are " + str(right) + " rights in this song.")
            print ("There are " + str(beats) + " beats.")
            nameDirections = ["left", "down", "up", "right"]
            directions = [left, down, up, right] 


       

runThrough = Button(
    root,
    padx=50, 
    pady=50, 
    text="Click to print number of each arrow", 
    command=checkDirections
)
runThrough.pack()
runThrough.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

def barGraph():
    LabelBar = Label(root, text = "Bar Activated")
    LabelBar.pack()
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.title("Directions")
    ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
    ypos = np.arange(len(nameDirections))
    plt.bar(nameDirections, directions)
    plt.show()

def ILovePie():
    LabelPie = Label(root, text = "Pie Activated")
    LabelPie.pack()
    plt.title("Directions")
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
    ypos = np.arange(len(nameDirections))
    plt.pie(directions, labels = nameDirections,autopct='%1.1f%%',
    shadow=True, startangle=90)
    plt.show()

barGraph = Button(root, text = "Click to show a bar graph", padx = 50, pady = 50, command = barGraph())
barGraph.grid(row = 1, column = 5)

runThrough.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if this isn't the answer you're looking for.

The error I recive when running this code is `_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed`. This error only appears when closing the application. The button doesn't appear at all. According to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818100/tkinter-tclerror-cant-invoke-button-command-application-has-been-destroyed) the error occurs because you call `root.mainloop()` before creating the button.

After I fixed that I had to rearrange the function `checkDirections()`.

Then you get the error `_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack`. According to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087020/fix-this-code-cannot-use-geometry-manager-grid-inside-which-already-has-slave):

> The error is telling you exactly what is wrong: you can't use both pack and grid with widgets that share a common parent

At this point I can't go furthur as I never used pack, numpy and matplotlib and I don't know how you want you window layed out.

This is where I got the `_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack` error and I hope you can continue from here:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import glob

root = Tk()

e = Entry(root, width=50)
e.pack()
root.title("Insert GUI Title Here")
root.geometry('600x400+50+50')
root.resizable(False, False)

nameDirections = []
directions = []


def openSmFile():
    folPath = filedialog.askdirectory()
    return folPath

def checkDirections():
    folPath = openSmFile()
    for fpath in glob.iglob(f'{folPath}/*'):
        if (fpath.endswith('.sm')):
            file = open(fpath, "r")
            lines = []
            lines = file.readlines()

            left = 0
            down = 0
            up = 0
            right = 0
            beats = 0

            for line in lines:
                i = 0
                if not ("," in line or "." in line or "#" in line or ";" in line or "-" in line or line == ""):
                    for alpha in line:
                        if i == 0 and alpha != "0":
                            left += 1
                        if i == 1 and alpha != "0":
                            down += 1
                        if i == 2 and alpha != "0":
                            up += 1
                        if i == 3 and alpha != "0":
                            right += 1
                        i += 1
                        beats += 1

            print("There are " + str(left) + " lefts in this song.")
            print("There are " + str(down) + " downs in this song.")
            print("There are " + str(up) + " ups in this song.")
            print("There are " + str(right) + " rights in this song.")
            print("There are " + str(beats) + " beats.")
            nameDirections = ["left", "down", "up", "right"]
            directions = [left, down, up, right]



runThrough = Button(
    root,
    padx=50,
    pady=50,
    text="Click to print number of each arrow",
    command=checkDirections
)
runThrough.grid(row=1, column=1)
runThrough.pack()
root.mainloop()






def barGraph():
    LabelBar = Label(root, text="Bar Activated")
    LabelBar.pack()
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.title("Directions")
    ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
    ypos = np.arange(len(nameDirections))
    plt.bar(nameDirections, directions)
    plt.show()


def ILovePie():
    LabelPie = Label(root, text="Pie Activated")
    LabelPie.pack()
    plt.title("Directions")
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
    ypos = np.arange(len(nameDirections))
    plt.pie(directions, labels=nameDirections, autopct='%1.1f%%',
            shadow=True, startangle=90)
    plt.show()


barGraph = Button(root, text="Click to show a bar graph", padx=50, pady=50, command=barGraph())
barGraph.grid(row=1, column=5)
```

If this wasn't the probelm then comment on this answer with the actual issue. Hope this helps!